# Reading trombone notes

Tags: technique, instruments, performing, band, trombone

I'm reading notes for my trombone for band, and there's these quarter notes, sometimes half notes, on top of another quarter note or half note. I have no idea what this means please help me!!! Band is tomorrow and I have no idea what they mean!!!

Comment: Could you add a picture? It will make your question much easier to answer well.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're looking at a dual part.  Is it headed 'Trombone 1' or 'Trombones 1/2' (or similar)?

[image]

Comment: If so, it's important the OP knows to play *either* the stems up *or* the stems down notes.

Comment: Typically the hint *a due* or additional upward stems should be present, to clarify that in the first two bars unisono is desired . On the other hand, there are no rests below/above either, so tha'ts probably meant.

Comment: Bars 20 and 22 seem odd, with a crossover. Any special reason?

Comment: Maybe to ensure full harmony when there is only one trombone?   This sort of arrangement was aimed at a very utilitarian musical world!

Comment: So is it safe to presume that with dots like this and only one trombone, that it's stems up that get played? What criteria are there?

Comment: Nothing is safe to presume in sloppily-presented notation such as this.   There's a lesson here to composers and engravers though.   Don't inflict dual parts on your players!   It's OK to have Trombones 1/2 share a stave in the full score, but do them the favour of separate parts.